# Return Html attribute with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, render

I am trying to return a fill colour based on a condition but this is sending the colour to all the tags. Please tell me a way to use "This." or "Self" function in Flask.

```
@app.route('/body/<part>')
def show_blog(part):
    claim = int(Assembled_ClaimsDF.loc[part])
    if claim>10000:
        return redirect(url_for('colour_red'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('colour_green'))

@app.route('/colour_red')
def colour_red():
    return render_template('new.html', colour = 'red')

@app.route('/colour_green')
def colour_green():
    return render_template('new.html', colour = 'yellow')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('new.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Each of your end points will render `new.html`. However in the last case (route '/') you are not passing any parameter `colour`. Is that intentional? Are you sure `Assembled_ClaimsDF.loc[part]` will concert to an int?

Comment: Yes, everything is intentional and Assembled_ClaimsDF.loc[part] is working fine, only the stated issue is there.

Comment: The problem may well be in `new.html`. Check that it using the parameter `colour` correctly.